# Laravel insert SQL not null violation, looking for a column thats not existing

Tags: sql, laravel, function, null, insert

My Laravel insert function in my controller looks for a "created_by" column that I do not have.

**Model**

```
class HmsBbrCategory extends Model
{
    public $timestamps = false;
    protected $table = 'hms_bbr_category';
    protected $fillable = ["id", "category_id", "category_name", 
        "category_description"];
}
```

**Controller**

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
        'category_name' => 'required|max:191',
        'category_description' => 'required|max:191',
    ]);
    if ($validator->fails()) {
        return response()->json([
            'status' => 400,
            'errors' => $validator->messages(),
        ]);
    } else {
        $categoryId = HmsBbrCategory::orderByDesc('id')->first();
        $autoIncId = $categoryId->id + 1;
        $category = new HmsBbrCategory;
        $category->category_name = $request->input('category_name');
        $category->category_description = $request->input('category_description');

        // Option tags
        $category->config_view_type = $request->input('config_view_type');
        $category->config_edit_type = $request->input('config_edit_type');
        $category->bbrmode_view_type = $request->input('bbrmode_view_type');

        $category->id = $autoIncId;
        $category->category_id = $autoIncId;
        $category->save();

        return response()->json([
            'status' => 200,
            'message' => 'Category Added!'
        ]);
    }
}
```

[image: 1]

I have a feeling that I may have the issue here in my request: `$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [` I was thinking that by `all()` I was taking all columns that I added. But this line may be the one looking for `created_by`. So how do I make an exemption not to have my code look for `created_by`?

Comment: can you show us the table?

Comment: That error is definitely an SQL error. Check the DB table and ensure the `created_by` column doesn't exist.

Comment: complete the $fillable with the options tags properties

Comment: You have a column `created_by` in your table, and it has `not null` and you are passing no data, so it is `null`, hence the error...

Answer (score 0):

Appears like your created_by column is NOT NULL, change to NULL